# Trouble setting locale (decimal symbol) settings in Python

Tags: python, locale

I have the problem, living in a country, where decimal symbol is "," not ".".
I tried to set locale settings in my python code.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'')
```

which resulted this if I print out to shell:

```
'decimal_point': ','
```

BUT when i try convert a string to float I get this:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '25,00'

I would appreciate any idea where Im doing wrong.
Of course I can easily change the `","` to `"."` in the text editor (tab delimited files) but I'd like to use something more professional :D

Thanks
-v

Comment: There is locale.atof()

Comment: Thanks Michael Butscher, thats correct. What I did not mention is that I have a long code, with several string to float conversation which was written in US environment, and I would avoid finding all the float() parts and change to locale.atof().

Comment: I really hope it's not possible to change the behavior of float() by changing the locale. Can you imagine the headache?

Comment: John Smith Optional, Can You imagine my headache? All datasets are with commas as decimal symbol...:D

Comment: Can't you use the string replace() method, or maybe a regex, to adapt your data?

Comment: Yes, thats the next step if there is no other solution, but at the end I have to replace again, when I write the files out, so kinda pain in ...I just tried if there is any other solution. Thanks

Comment: Absolutely not the one I wished, but solved with replace, at the end need to replace back (i chose this country with its decimal symbol :D)

`for idx in range(len(data_lines[lidx])):`
`data_lines[lidx][idx]=str(data_lines[lidx][idx]).replace(",",".")`

Comment: It's a tricky solution, but you can also try redefine float builtin function with `__builtins__.float = locale.atof`